# Javascript: 'Protected' Scoping

Tags: javascript, scope

How does one implement 'protected variables' in javascript?

```
var DIM = {
  makeOneDim: function(x) {
    var magic = Math.random();
    return {
      dist: function() {
        return x * magic;
      }
    };
  },
  makeTwoDim: function(x,y) {
    var o = DIM.makeOneDim(x);
    o.dist = function() {       
      magic *= Math.random();
      return Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y) * magic;
      // !! cant access 'private' variable magic !!
    }
    return o;
  }
};
var o = DIM.makeOneDim(123);
var oo = DIM.makeTwoDim(1,2);
console.log(o.dist() + oo.dist());
```

I know in this example it would be possible to make a 'public getter', but i would still want to mutate the magic variable from within makeTwoDim's scope and hide it from its instances.

It would also be nice if I could somehow prevent recreating the dist functions on each creation of an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this suit your needs? It uses a revealing module pattern to make `magic` private and return the functions. As such there is no need to call `makeOneDim` from `makeTwoDim`.

```
var DIM = (function () {

  var magic = Math.random();

  function makeOneDim(x) {
    return {
      dist: function() {
        return x * magic;
      }
    };
  }

  function makeTwoDim(x, y) {
    return {
      dist: function() {
        magic *= Math.random();
        return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) * magic;
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    makeOneDim: makeOneDim,
    makeTwoDim: makeTwoDim
  }

});

var o = DIM().makeOneDim(123);
var oo = DIM().makeTwoDim(1,2);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/308jf29z/)

Comment: yes! this works great, but i do worry about performance having to recreate a DIM instance each time, especially if I were to implement this logic in creating libraries.

Comment: In this and your case they're not object instances in the class-sense. You create those with constructors. I wouldn't worry too much about performance unless you're noticing a real drop. A constructor _might_ help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you could engineer this, but the simplest would be to just keep the functions together:

```
var DIM = {
  makeOneDim: function(x) {
    var magic = Math.random();
    var dist = function() {
      return x * magic;
    };

    var dist2 = function(y, y) {       
      magic *= Math.random();
      return Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y) * magic;
    };

    return {
      dist : dist,
      dist2 : dist2,
    };
  }
};
```

(and, did you really mean to change the value of `magic` with each call?)

Comment: This won't work because `magic` is still local to the first function.

Comment: @Malvolio cool that does work. I'd want to avoid the bloat though in scenarios where I only need oneDim objects. Even more so if i were to add on more functionality to DIM / twoDim / anything else not pertinent to oneDim objects.

Comment: @Andy -- `magic` is local to `makeOneDim` (huh, I should have changed the name).  It is "closed" -- which means exactly the opposite of what it sounds like, it means "available" -- to both `dist` and `dist2`.

Comment: Right, sorry, wasn't paying attention to what you'd done.

Comment: @iluvAS -- that "bloat" is 4 bytes, far less than any other solution you could come up with.  "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time." -- Donald Knuth

Comment: That's the second time today I've seen that Knuth quote - the other wasn't on here... :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to determine the value of `magic` within `makeTwoDim` by dividing `o.dist()` by `x`

```
var o = DIM.makeOneDim(x);    
var magic = o.dist() / x;
console.log(magic)
```

Comment: wow cool workaround! But this exposes magic to instances as well in which case my example is flawed, but I'm sure you know what I'm getting at.

Comment: @iluvAS _"But this exposes magic to instances as well"_ Not certain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make environment with scope function.

### The jQuery way :

```
var myClass;

(function () {
    var a = 0; // private var

    function protect_function() {
        //...
    }

    window.myClass = {
        public_function: function () { }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm likely to collect rotten tomatoes, but I'd like to say that I disagree with the use of "protected" or "private" variables in the scope of JavaScript OOP. There are no builtin safeguards in JavaScript, developpers are doomed to be better than the others, that's it :-D Don't try to mimic Java, just take it as an opportunity to improve your programming skills. Thus, this code looks perfect to me:

```
AClass = function () {
  // `rdm` should never change
  this.rdm = Math.random();
};
```